# Update existing list without reloading entire page

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm figuring out what's the best way to update a current list of results from an API call, with a new list of results from an API call.

I'm making API request to news API and loading them into the index page when it first loads:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    request("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=" + initialQ + "&category=sports&pageSize=10&page=" + page + "&sortBy=relevance&apiKey=" + apiKey, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            let data = JSON.parse(body);

            totalResults = data.totalResults;

            console.log(totalResults)

            let articles = scripts.articlesArr(data);

            let filteredArticles = scripts.filteredArr(articles);

            res.render("index", { filtered: filteredArticles });

        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
            console.log(response.body);
        }
    });
});
```

Then the user will toggle two buttons to get more results, or go back a page:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    let inputValue = req.body.page;
    let pages = Math.ceil(totalResults / 10)

    page = scripts.iteratePages(inputValue, page, pages);

    request("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=" + initialQ + "&category=sports&pageSize=10&page=" + page + "&sortBy=relevance&apiKey=" + apiKey, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            let data = JSON.parse(body);

            let articles = scripts.articlesArr(data);

            let filteredArticles = scripts.filteredArr(articles);

            res.render("index", { filtered: filteredArticles });

        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
            console.log(response.body);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm aware of Socket io, but I was wondering if there are other means or methods of achieving this? From what I understand, I can update frontend content via the front end - but with my current set up I'd much prefer to update from the back end

EJS code:

```
    <div id="container">
        <% for(var i=0; i < filtered.length; i++) { %>
            <ul>
                <li><%= filtered[i].title %></li>
                <li><%= filtered[i].date %></li>
                <li><img src="<%= filtered[i].image%>" /></li>
                <li><%=filtered[i].description%></li>
                <li><%= filtered[i].link %></li>
            </ul>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" name="page" value="next">Get more results</button>
                <button type="submit" name="page" value="prev">Go back a page</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: you can use ajax to get data from server side, and use template engine on client side to render and show data. for ajax you can check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, for client side template engines you can check https://github.com/janl/mustache.js or https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/. By the way there are too many template engines. keywords are ajax and client side template engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bi-directional communication we can use WebSockets (with a library like Socket.IO), for uni-directional server-to-client we can use EventSource, and for uni-directional client-to-server we use good ol' HTTP, through `fetch` or  `XMLHttpRequest` in the browser API (this is referred to as AJAX, though I think most devs just says "client calls the server" these days). For 99% of use cases what we want is client-to-server over HTTP. If I understand correctly then you want stuff to happen when the users pushes a button. That's a case of client-to-server.

1. User pushes button
2. Client calls our new API endpoint `/articles` with `fetch` to get more articles: `const data = await fetch('localhost:8080/articles'); const articles = await data.json()`. A simplified version of the code for `/articles` looks something like `app.get('/articles', (req, res) => request("https://newsapi.org").then(articles => /* do stuff with articles here */res.send(result))`. This end point returns json instead of html (which our `/` endpoint returns)
3. Our server calls newsapi. Newsapi anserrs our server. Our server answers the client.
4. Then we need some data binding/templating that ensures that the DOM is updated with the new articles. This is functionality that libs like React and Angular supply. But for learning purposes and to keep things simple you can do something like `articles.forEach(a => {const el = document.createElement('li'); el.innerHtml = a; document.getElementById('articles').appendChild(el)})`, assuming a tag `<ul id="articles">...` where articles are supposed to show up exists (you probably want to do something more complex with your articles, but you get the idea)
5. Page hasn't reloaded

Update: some code review :)

- use template literals. `"https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=" + initialQ + "&category=sports&pageSize=10&page=" + page + "&sortBy=relevance&apiKey=" + apiKey` -> `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=${initialQ}&category=sports&pageSize=10&page=${page}&sortBy=relevance&apiKey=${apiKey}`
- Prefer `const` over `let`
- Use new lines when you're lines get very long (many go by 80 columns as preferred max width)
- It looks like you do one `ul` for each article and one `li` for each property on the article. `ul` is a list (unordered list) and `li` is a list item. So one `ul` should contain many `li`, and each `li` should contain one item (in this case an article). You can read more about semantics in web development [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics)

Comment: This logic is great, thank you. But I had two questions. With point 2, am I requesting a new JSON from the server (that originally called the API) or from the API URL via front end? I'm not sure how this would work with what I currently have set up - see second block of code. And secondly, does point 4 update the EJS template and remove the existing? Or append new list elements to below the current set of articles? As ideally, I'd like to update the existing set of articles

Comment: I updated my answer.

The flow is client -> server -> thirdparty api. It works with what you currently have, but you need to rewrite your endpoint for POST `/` a little bit (I call it GET `/articles` instead)

The EJS has been transformed to HTML at this point. EJS only exist server side on the first render (EJS is for server side templating if I'm not mistaken). It's up to you how the list is updated, but my example code is for appending to the existing list.